# Using nginx for proxy_pass to local port opened by other user

Tags: nginx

I am trying to expose a (streamlit) application on port 80, that is running on port 8501 on the same computer as nginx. The streamlit application is started by user1, the nginx.conf file is unchanged from installation:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

and then I specify the server in myserver.conf in the /etc/nginx/conf.d folder:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8501/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-8501.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-8501.log;
}
```

When I go to the servers address in a web browser I always only see the nginx own homepage, no redirection to 8501 takes place, and nothing in the error logs. If I empty the whole nginx.conf file so that it looks like:

```
events {
}
http {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

everything works. So what is happening? I would like to "hide" the streamlit application behind a proxy like above, so what is wrong in my initial setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to another `.conf` file in this directory `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` because in `nginx.conf` this directory included.

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

You can comment this line or remove that `.conf` file then everything works.

```
rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf
```